# The space need of the strcat_s function

Tags: c++

I try to add an char array with my String, when run to the strcat_s the vs2013 told me the buffer is too small, but i think i did give enough space, even when i make temp.str much larger, it still didn't work. So what's happening here. By the way this is a friend function of the class String.

```
String operator+(const char a[],const String & st)
{
    String temp;

    temp.len = std::strlen(a) + st.len+1;
    temp.str = new char[temp.len];

    strcpy_s(temp.str, std::strlen(a)+1, a);

    strcat_s(temp.str, std::strlen(st.str)+1,st.str);
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Why not use std::string?

Comment: You know the second argument is supposed to be the buffer size, right? So you're telling it the buffer is smaller than it actually is.

Comment: I think the error message is that size of temp. str is smaller then the need but I don't know why,